# FBSDKAccess token returning nil every second time i restart the app on simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, facebook-graph-api

I want to obtain the access token for facebook user. Once the user has successfully logged in and granted access, I get the current access token. When i restart the app for first time then current access token doesn't come nil but when i restart the app again it comes nil. Anyway when user logs in again, it shows message "You have already verified this app".

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I think I have understood about your question: You might want to store your access token in your User Defaults (by using NSUserDefaults).

Comment: By default is should give accesstoken when ever i m trying to get it unless it has expired.